# adding attributes to data.xml using xbl component in form builder

Tags: orbeon

How can we send *hint* of **Single-Line Text** component, like xml **attributes** in Orbeon Form Builder to data.xml?
For example:
hint: first-name="Erik" last-name="Bruchez" email="info@orbeon.com"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<form>
<contact first-name="Erik" last-name="Bruchez" email="info@orbeon.com" />
</form>
```

Now send button generate data.xml like :

```
<contact>
  <first-name>Erik</first-name> 
  <last-name>Bruchez</last-name> 
  <email>info@orbeon.com</email> 
  <phone>6505555555</phone> 
</contact>
```

Or maybe is there some ways to define data.xml attributes from Form Builder?

Comment: I am not sure what you refer to by *hint*. In XForms, a hint is attached to a control, and for instance with forms created with Form Builder, the hint is a short help message shown by default below the control. I will answer assuming that your question is about bind a control to an attribute instead of an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look to me like you're trying to bind a control to an attribute (`/form/contact/@first-name`),  instead of an element (`/form/contact/first-name`). You can do this if you write XForms by hand, but not if you're creating the form with Form Builder. With Form Builder, the structure of the XML used to collect the data is automatically created for you by Form Builder.

If this XML needs to go to another system that expects data in a different format, then you can, on submission, implement your own service to which the data is sent, and you can do the transformation in that service, for instance using XSLT.

Comment: I found `<hint>KATO = "9959595" КRP="908"</hint>` when I pushed Edit Source button in Form Builder. How can I send this code with data.xml?

Comment: The hint is something you entered when you create the form (in Form Builder); this isn't something that users enter when filling out the form, so it isn't part of the form data. If your end points needs this info, it can always retrive the form through the persistence layer. Is this something that would make sense for you?

Comment: thank you for your response. I agree with you, but we want to save in data.xml some attributes like KATO = "9959595" КRP="908", which we define when create a form in Form Builder. It's our idea to write this attributes in the hint section. Any different ideas? Could you talk to me how exactly can I retrieve the hint using persistence layer?

Comment: we have created the form. [link](http://ideone.com/4nVyQG) in Form Builder. The data.xml is looks like [link](http://ideone.com/K28pkr). But we need a different format xml file: `<datasource><item KCP="135" KRP="105" NKIPC="105" kato="193200000" date="2012-10-19" B2="60"/><item KCP="135" KRP="105" NKIPC="106" kato="193200000" date="2012-10-19" B2="40"/><item KCP="135" KRP="105" NKIPC="107" kato="193200000" date="2012-10-19" B2="80"/></datasource>`. One idea is send data.xml to some service on java and transform the xml data using XSLT. Does my approach is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can use the `workflow-send` button, which allows you to configure Orbeon to POST the XML to your service. Then there, you can decorate/transform the data. http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button

Comment: Another option, which applies if you just want to add attributes or elements to the instance is to edit the form in Form Builder, and there to edit the instance to add your additional attributes. When doing so, be careful not to change the structure of the instance. You can add attributes or sibling elements, but can't rename or change the nesting of existing elements.

Comment: thank you for your response. Could you provide me with an example how service can recieve xml data by POST method? I dunno how to retrieve the xml data in servlet. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `<%@ page import="org.dom4j.io.SAXReader"%>
<%@ page import="org.dom4j.Document"%>
<%@ page import="org.dom4j.Element"%>
   response.setContentType("application/xml");
  SAXReader xmlReader = new SAXReader();     
  if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {        
Document queryDocument = xmlReader.read(request.getInputStream());
String query = queryDocument.getRootElement().getStringValue();    
    }
%>` Is this code correct? When I push a send button **class org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException** appear. What's wrong? How can I print the xml data in browser?

Comment: where I should write smth. like ` <xforms:submission id="do-query"
    ref="instance('query')" method="post"
    replace="instance" instance="photos"
    resource="/xforms-jsp/flickr-search/service-search.jsp"/> `?

Comment: This is an example in Java (in a JSP) which reads the POSTed XML, using Dom4j. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/examples-jsp/flickr-search/service-search.jsp This seems to be close to what you are doing. You don't need to write the `<xforms:submission>`; it is "written" for you in the form definition by Form Builder.

Comment: If you don't see an obvious difference between your code and the on I am linking to, you'll need to debug this. First, I would set the Orbeon debugging to "development mode"; see: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-logging#TOC-Development-configuration. Then you should find more information in the `orbeon.log`, in particular what Orbeon sent to your service, and what I received back.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have created an http service in Form Builder. http url at wich service reside is my jsp page.`if ("POST".equals(request.getMethod())) {        
        Document document = xmlReader.read(request.getInputStream());
  String result = document.asXML().toString();` In fact I need a String, but `document.asXML().toString();` doesn't work. How can I get String from Document?

Comment: See how the `domToString()` does it in Orbeon's `Dom4jUtils`  https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xml/dom4j/Dom4jUtils.java#L120. It is calling some other methods that are all in the same file.

Comment: thank you for your help. Now it works. But there are another question. Actually, we have an invisible section(visibility=false) in form. And when we send data.xml using workflow button it sends xml data without an invisible section xml attributes and values. How to send all data which exists in form in xml?

Comment: when we push email button it sends all data in xml (with invisible section data). Maybe we should change smth. in properties-local.xml?

Comment: Right, there is a property you can set to tell Orbeon Forms not to prune non-relevant nodes before it sends the data. See "Pruning non-relevant nodes" on http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Workflow-send-button. But note that this was added post-3.9, so you'll need to use a 4.0 milestone build for this.